# How to trigger a rule in an InfoPath form from action done on another field

Tags: infopath

I have a form with a Name field. The Name field has the set of rules shown in this image on the right. when the user changes any of the fields shown by the mouse icons, i have a rule to Set Name field to "". i do that in hopes that the change would trigger the Name field to run it's rules and generate the correct name based on other parameters/variables.

it doesn't work.

any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the reason this didn't work is because if the rule changes the name to the same thing it already is, then it won't fire.

i had to change name to " " and then back to blank, in order to get it to fire.